# NPM - "npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents" when trying to install vue-cli on AWS/EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, vue.js, npm-install

I'm trying to have `vue-cli` installed on AWS.

My permissions look ok and I'm using `node v4.4.5`.

After running `npm install --global vue-cli`, the cursor blinks for about 30 seconds, then this error message is shown and nothing is installed in the directory:

```
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.1.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a warning, so it should still work without it, specially considering [`FSEvents`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents) is an `OS X` API, so if you are using another `OS`, which is the case, it's normal to get that warning and the library that is using it will most likely have an alternative for other `OSs`.

Also, it has already been asked in the official `vue-cli` GitHub repo:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/170

I'm not sure what you mean with *the directory is empty*, but just in case:

- When you install a package locally (without the `-global` flag) they should appear in a folder `node_modules` in your current directory.
- When you install a package globally, on unix systems they are usually in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`.

  Running `npm root -g` should tell you where the global packages have been installed.

Comment: Just dies there. Nothing gets installed in my EC2 instance.

Comment: @EdwardPotter Which empty directory are you referring to? As you are installing the packages globally, those will not be installed in a `node_modules` directory in your current one, but in (usually) `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`. You can run `npm root -g` to see where global packages are installed on your system. Please, check if they are being installed there.

Comment: This worked!  sudo npm install -g vue-cli. I'm still getting up to speed on node.  thanks, marked you answer as correct. Yes, it was the global thing.

Comment: Great, I assumed you where using `sudo` as you said permissions were fine and didn't mention anything about an `EACCES` error, which is the one that you usually get in that case.